How to remove additional logs printed by `set -x` in bash
I am in Windows and use Git Bash. When I run set -x, I get the following logs every command
$ set -x
++ __git_ps1
++ local exit=0
++ local pcmode=no
++ local detached=no
++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
++ case "$#" in
++ printf_format=' (%s)'
++ local ps1_expanded=yes
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '4.4.23(1)-release' ']'
++ shopt -q promptvars
++ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
++ repo_info=
++ rev_parse_exit_code=128
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return 0

... even on an empty line (just pressing enter)
$
++ __git_ps1
++ local exit=0
++ local pcmode=no
++ local detached=no
++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
++ case "$#" in
++ printf_format=' (%s)'
++ local ps1_expanded=yes
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '4.4.23(1)-release' ']'
++ shopt -q promptvars
++ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
++ repo_info=
++ rev_parse_exit_code=128
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return 0

I didn't find those commands in my %userprofile% (C:\Users\xxx\) or its subdirectories (but I may have missed them). Also tried removing my .bashrc and .bash_profile.
How do I prevent set -x from printing those because it makes set -x unusable.
Thanks!

See Git in Bash.  One way to fix your problem may be to set a simple PS1 (e.g. PS1='$ ') before using set -x.

That fixed it! I now added PS1='$ ' in my .bashrc to always set it.
If possible, please post an answer so I could mark it as the solution. Thank you!

set -x at the top level may not be useful and force you to change the prompt and other stuff.
If you want to debug a script just use
bash -x script

